# Hypervisor The operation cannot be performed while the object is in it's current state

Tags: centos, virtualization, hyper-v

I attempted to reboot one of my VMs in the Hyper-V Manager. It's a Centos VM and all of my other centos machines are behaving as they should although I can't get this particular one to boot. I'm a jack of all trades at my job, although I don't know much about Hyper V so I can't provide the necessary information for you straight away although I'll post it when you tell me what I need to describe!

Why won't my machine start, and is it possible to find out what state it's in. The HV Manager says it's Off.

Thanks,
Harry

Edit: I can't add an answer for 8 hours as I have no reputation on serverfault, although here it is:

The HV Manager service was restarted and now it's functioning correctly.

Comment: +1 you share the solution in some way.

Comment: @harry .  I think it's been long enough.  Append and close this monster before it's allowed to vote, okay?